# How to timeout rabbitmq consumer ?

Tags: go, rabbitmq

I have rabbitmq consuming the queue but once client is subscribed it stays consuming queue forever. Is there a timeout to declare and exit i.e. after queue is empty ?

```
 msgs, err := ch.Consume(
                q.Name, // queue
                "",     // consumer
                true,   // auto-ack
                false,  // exclusive
                false,  // no-local
                false,  // no-wait
                nil,    // args
        )
for msg := range msgs { 
                log.Printf("Received message with message: %s", msg.Body)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [the standard Go pattern for timing out](https://blog.golang.org/go-concurrency-patterns-timing-out-and).

Here is a working example.

```
const duration = 3 * time.Second
timer := time.NewTimer(duration)
for {
    select {
    case d := <-msgs:
        timer.Reset(duration)
        fmt.Printf("Received a message: %s\n", d.Body)
    case <- timer.C:
        fmt.Println("Timeout !")
        os.Exit(1)
    }
}
```

It probably needs some polishing, e.g. I suppose it would be better to stop the timer when you receive the message and enable it again when you are done processing it, but this should get you started.

Comment: so like insert it into the for loop above with break ?

Comment: Yes, and also reset the timer every time you read from the channel.

Comment: I've used go timeout pattern with case <-timeout: os.Exit(1) but it doesnt exit in the that rabbitmq loop

Comment: This is really interesting. I tried and looks like it does not timeout in that for 'msg := range msgs {}'  loop. It does if setup outside rabbitmq  loop

Comment: A for… range loop on a channel is like a for… select on only one channel; in this case, the RabbitMQ channel. To timeout in this fashion, you need a select on two channels, the RabbitMQ channel and the timeout channel.

Comment: It works like a charm , great , really appreciate ! I can see some more examples here https://mmcgrana.github.io/2012/09/go-by-example-timers-and-tickers.html